# send json to laravel api route with json validate

Tags: json, laravel, postman

i sending post data to laravel route like this photo
[image]

my validate request is this:

```
return [
            'mobile' => ['required', 'string'],
            'withdraws' => 'required|json',
        ];
```

but i got this error:
*"The withdraws field must be a valid JSON string."*

Comment: Please check similar question available on stack,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says (and the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-json)) the "json" validation rule asserts that the field contains a valid JSON **string** not an object

for your case, you can use [dot notation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#a-note-on-nested-attributes) to validate the nested fields

otherwise, if you want to just validate that it contains an object no matter what fields it contains, you'll need to create your own custom validator for that, as Laravel AFAIK doesn't have a rule for that.